# How do I cast a NUMBER value to a single CHAR in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, casting, plsql, char, int

In pretty much any normal programming language, one can cast an integer/short/byte into a char with ease using a cast similar to this

```
char alpha = (char)123;
```

I am trying to do this in an Oracle database.  I have column of type CHAR(1 BYTE) and I want to be able to store NUMBER values (non of which will be larger than around 30) in it.  The CAST function isn't letting me do it.

```
rank := 10;
CAST(rank as CHAR(1))
```

where rank is a NUMBER variable.  I get an error:

`Value from cast operand is larger than cast target size.`

How is this done in Oracle PL/SQL?

Comment: You want to cast a two digit number into a one character CHAR. The error tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: A character is 1 byte, the decimal number 10 can be represented with one byte (00001010).  I am using the definition of the word 'cast' that I as a programmer am used to which may be different than SQL's definition.

Comment: "Oracle stores a number in base 100 format, each byte can store 2 digits, one byte is always reserved for the exponent" (From: http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17375). You're going to need a bigger column.

Comment: @Ollie - I didn't know it worked that way, I thought it was character length.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I direct you both to my comment in northpole's answer.  I don't care about storing a human-readable character with any significance whatsoever.  I am trying to store a single-byte value in a single-byte column that just happens to be expecting a char instead of a number.

Comment: @NathanDaniels r u referring to the dec value of a char? (dec 65 => char 'A').  If so, then for ASCII anyway, use chr function: select chr(65) from dual;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment on @northpole's answer...

The closest to what you want might not be exactly correct but the [CHR](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/chr.php) function would convert the numeric to it's ascii equivalent.
i.e. `alpha := chr(113);` would put the char "q" into the alpha variable thereby storing your numeric "113" as a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options.  You can use TO_CHAR and do something like:

```
TO_CHAR(rank,'99')
```

Or use the CAST function and fix your attempt by providing a larger CHAR:

```
CAST(rank as CHAR(2))
```

The reason for that is as Ollie described in his comment.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my problem.  I am not trying to get a string representation of a number.  What I am trying to do is essentially store a single-byte number in a column that is expecting a single-byte character.  In theory, this should be simple: a one-byte number will fit perfectly fine in a one-byte column.  For example, in Java or C#, I can store the number 113 (which keen-eyed observers will note is three character long when displayed) into a single-byte char variable simply by saying char a = (char)113;  The resulting character is 'q' but that is completely irrelevant to me.

Comment: The closest to what you want might not be exactly correct but the CHR function would convert the numeric to it's ascii equivalent. i.e. `alpha := chr(113);` would put the char "q" into the alpha variable thereby storing your numeric "113" as a single byte.

Comment: That is almost exactly what I am looking for.  Thank you, Ollie.

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer for future people searching this question.

Comment: wow, I was way off in how I understood the issue.  thanks for clearing it up @Ollie

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SUBSTR(CAST(rank as CHAR(2)), 2, 1)
```